# Run job on condition of lic availability

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I’m new to new Jenkins , I’m looking for some guidance how to find a solution for the following Implementation.

I have 2 windows slaves , on this slaves I have an app licensed where only 10 processes of this app can run simultaneously per user. (the Jenkins user in this case)

I need Jenkins to know before running a windows batch script job if there is availability to run the job . Meaning that, Jenkins needs to know if there are app slots (< 10 ) available on any existent nodes and dispatch the job. If not any wait and retry.

All suggestions are very welcome

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845889/jenkins-resource-management

Answer (score 0):

you can create 10 executers for your windows , and you will make sure that NOT more than 10 jobs will run at the same time.

or you can use this plugin to setup some limitation for your system - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin